# how to show UIalertview while application is running but iphone is locked?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uialertview

i want to show a alert when my app is running but phone is locked..we can say in power save mode. is there a way to show alertview without Push-Notification service when phone is idle and app is running.

Comment: btw, Rahul - the more answers you accept on questions you ask, the more people are likely to answer your questions.

Comment: What about a Local Notification?

Comment: @RandyMarsh Local Notification introduced in ios 4.0 onwards I asked the question when it was 3.0 sdk

Comment: @RahulVyas: Oops, didn't notice that! :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is locked, then your app is blocked.  The only possibility (which I've never tried) might be to push a notification to the phone.